# How can I remove unused datasources from Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Report Builder 3.0 to create, deploy and manage reports for my .NET application. I create a new `datasource` with network credentials which are stored in the report server and point to that shared datasource when I build the reports.

**My question is:**

Why can't I remove old `datasource` connections from Report Builder 3.0 `Data Source Properties` wizard dialog? I've already deleted those unused `datasource` from report server. But report builder is still showing them as available `datasource`. Are there any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone proposed a solution for this problem on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/679232/cannot-remove-old-unusable-data-source-connections-from-report-builder-3-0-wizard-dialog) since 2011.

Alternatively, you can clear all recent items from Report Builder Options Dialog (`File->Options`). But please take note that it will also clear your connections from `Recent Sites and Servers`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: So I cannot delete one by one?

Comment: Yes currently it is only possible to clear all items.

Comment: Old post, but Google led me to this question. AMissico has a better solution that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

Edit %localappdata%\Microsoft\Report Builder\11.0.0.0\user.config and delete the obsolete values.

Comment: This solution works, you can remove individual data sources, datasets, and reports. It should be the answer.